# seekbar issues when using custom thumb

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am having troubles with a seek bar, i am trying to create an audio settings fragment but when i customize my seekbar thumb i noticed that the progress does not start and end in where i would like to.

[image: there is a small black space that i would like to remove and fill the full paternt.]

I tried lot of things but i cannot find the solution.

I would also like to add white lines in the background like from 1 to 10.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like this simple line fixed the thing:

```
android:thumbOffset="5dp"
```

Thanks anyway and hope this can help someone.